# In C is there a way to set a maximum width for an integer output?

Tags: c, io, hex, negative-number

I am printing hexadecimal numbers in sequence to make an opcode for an assembler in C. I have everything perfect except for when the displacement is negative. Now I only have 3 spaces available for the displacement and when it is say -11(base 10) I convert that and get `fffffff5` as my answer. I want to limit this so that only `ff5` is displayed. Is there a way to do this? When printing positive numbers because of restrictions the number will never be greater than `7FF` so I get no issue there. But with negative numbers it will always print 8 hex numbers and I want just the 3 right most digits, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: But you know that 0xfffffff5 and 0xff5 are different values?

Comment: @deviantfan, not if they both are representing `-11` in 32-bit vs 12-bit signed two's complement representations.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, and that´s why in the C code with 32bit vars it will need special treatment (when reading it in again or something). That´s why I´m writing this, somehow I doubt OP is aware of this if the only concern are spaces.

Comment: I assumed he meant 3 hex place values available in his instruction encoding. That is, the displacement is a 12-bit relative offset.

Comment: You are correct. I am only allowed 3 hex place values in the instruction encoding. The range for my pc relative addressing is from -2048 - 2047 with only 3 hex values to represent the number.

Answer (score 2):

You can just truncate before printing:

```
unsigned int x = -11;
printf("%03x\n", x & 0xfff);
```

Example output:

```
$ ./example 
ff5
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I really appreciate that it fixed it perfectly. Is there a webpage you got that from? I had been searching for a way to truncate integers and couldn't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the values to the range -0x800 to 0x7FF works as suggested by [@Carl Norum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116908/carl-norum) with `x & 0xfff`.

In *theory*, `printf()` also needs to control locale which literally could print out a whole lot more but practically is not a concern.  Of course code could use.

```
char buf[4];
buf[0] = 0;
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%03x", x & 0xFFF);
fputs(buf, stdout);
```

But this is a bit of [belt *and* suspenders](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belt_and_suspenders).

Comment: @Carl Norum If you mean that pesky extra `'F'` - fixed.

Comment: Yup - that's it. I think I was missing what was going on at first. Now I get it.